# Horizontal bar chart with date using echart

Tags: echarts, echarts-for-react

I am new to echart and trying to construct a bar chart as shown in the [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiqa1.png) using the echarts-for-react library.
X-Axis represent the date (1st of every month), Y-Axis represent each record. The bar should be displayed relative to the current date. The color of the bar is based on the status.

So far, I have come up with the below options, not sure, how to render negative bar for the past date in relation to the current date.
Can someone please help?

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Andromeda',
    status: 'Green',
    date: '2023-02-28T00:00:00',
  },
  {
    name: 'Circinus',
    status: 'Red',
    date: '2023-04-30T00:00:00',
  },
  {
    name: 'Cartwheel',
    status: 'Orange',
    date: '2023-06-30T00:00:00',
  },
  {
    name: 'Omega',
    status: 'Blue',
    date: '2023-10-31T00:00:00'
  }
]

option = {
  dataset: { source: data },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    axisLabel: {
      formatter(value) {
        return new Date(value).toLocaleDateString();
      },
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'bar',
      itemStyle: {
        color({ dataIndex }) {
          const { status } = data[dataIndex];
          switch (status) {
            case 'Green':
              return '#4CAF50';
            case 'Red':
              return '#F44336';
            case 'Orange':
              return '#FF9800';
            case 'Blue':
              return '#2196F3';
            default:
              return '#000000';
          }
        },
      },
      encode: {
        x: 'date',
        y: 'status',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```